# How to run two RDP sessions simultaneously in different WSL Ubuntu installations (Windows)

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, remote-desktop, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I have searched googled a lot, such as modify the group policy for RDP, but it does not work.

In Windows 10, I installed two WSL2 versions of Ubuntu -- One 20.04, and the other 20.10. In both of them, I have installed xrdp.  Each of them alone works fine with RDP.

However, I just cannot connect to two RDP sessions at the same time. If I do so, one version of Ubuntu will always be a black screen in RDP, while the other works fine.

I just want to have two RDP sessions work at the same time correctly.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: I believe that I have reproduced this.  My Ubuntu 20.04 XRDP usually works.  However, when I was trying to get my openSUSE Tumbleweed XRDP set up (mainly to see if I could reproduced your problem), I ran into the same issue as you.  When I started the xrdp server in Tumbleweed (even though it was fully working) on port 3391 and the Ubuntu xrdp server on 3390, I ended up with the black-screen issue on the Ubuntu session (which had been working previously).  Stopping both and starting *just* the Ubuntu one resolved the issue.  Not sure *why* yet, though.

Comment: Thank you @NotTheDr01ds  For now a solution is just perhaps use Hyper-V, or some virtual machine software.